# How to get the data from the node other than triggered by onCreate using cloud functions written in TypeScript for Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase as well as to TypeScript, I searched a lot to get value at reference other than triggered value, I found answers in JavaScript but I am writing functions using typescript for realtime database for android.
I got answers like using event.data.ref but I am unable to use that.

[this is the link to the image of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKJV.png)
.

In the above image I have written OnCreate trigger in typescript at the node -

***Trips / { uId } / { tId }***

And whenever this is going to be triggered I want to write at the same location but what I want to write is at location -

***Cars / { carId }***

so how should I fetch data from the node other that triggered node.
Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is really no different from JavaScript in terms of APIs.  There is nothing "special" for TS that's different from JS.  For both languages, you should use the provided JavaScript API documentation to understand how things work.  For libraries that provide type bindings for TS, you just know the types of arguments and return values more specifically within your code editor.  All that said, what I'm about to say next is applicable to both TS and JS.

In your [Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), an [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onCreate) will provide you with a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) as the first argument.  That object has a [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot#ref) property which points to the location of the update.  If you want to access any other location in the database, simply use the [root](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#root) property of that reference to get to the top level of the database, and use that reference to construct other references to locations you're interested in.

Comment: Thank yo sir :) I will try this.

Comment: Sir can you please show me how should I read the value of data from node other than triggered one just the way you told to use root property to get the reference,It is showing error when i attach val() to the reference created by root to the desired location